# Which method/algorithm delivers the best output quality when scaling up low resolution to high resolution images?

Tags: image, image-processing, printing, imagemagick, resolution

I am going to try and be as specific as possible.

I am starting an invitation business that will allow people to customize their invitations online and then send it to print.  I am trying to figure out the best way to take the preview image they are mocking up and output it so its high resolution enough to print.

I know svg would be my best bet, but the problem is half of my designs are not vectors, but rather 300 dpi raster images.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could take these 300 dpi images, shrink them down so I can create a preview image and then scale them back up so I can print them?

I have tried saving as PNG files, but the problem is they get saved for the web at 72 dpi.

Comment: Save two versions. One for preview. One for printing. Also, pngs are only good for vector like images. For general photo images, they get much, much larger than the equivalent jpeg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't scale down an image to a low resolution preview-version and then scale it back up to high resolution and preserve the high resolution quality.  You will lose a ton of detail in the original image if you scale it down, then scale it back up.

I think you need to rethink the flow of your application here.  The normal way to do this is to create a preview image and let the user use it in the web UI to create their invitation, but when they do modifications on it, you store those as metadata that describes the modifications, not as a modified image.  Then, when it comes time to create the high resolution image, you go back to the original, make a copy of it and you apply the metadata modifications to the high resolution image copy, thus preserving the maximum resolution.

If you want to make sure you're showing them a correct preview before they bless it for printing, you can make one of the last approval processes be a step where you generate the high resolution image combined with the metadata edits that they've done and then you take that high resolution image and make a web-sized version of that as their final web preview.  You would use the high resolution version you created for printing.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to scale up an image from a lower resolution, this can be easily done with ImageMagick's `convert` command. It is very straightforward:

```
convert  input.png  -scale 400%  4x-input.png
```

However, there are some very advanced algorithms available which would provide a much better quality of the output, if you knew how to whip them into action from the commandline.

Consider the following input image (original filesize is 7 kByte, dimensions are 108x135 pixels):

[image: Original PNG, 'ophthalmologist test chart']

Now scale it up to 16 times the number of pixels (or 4 times for each dimension)...

1. ...first with the above *'straightforward scaling'* command,
2. ...then with a *'better scaling quality'* command.

Compare these two results:

[image: Straightforward 400% scaling result]
[image: Better quality 400% scaling result]

Note the difference of filesizes as well:

- both resulting images have a size of 432x540 pixels,
- but the 'better quality' one uses only 72 kByte of diskspace,
- whereas the 'straightforward' scaled one uses more: 87.5 kByte!

You want to see the result for a photo? Here we go...

Input photo:

[image: Old man's photo]

The results of ImageMagick's 'straightforward scaling' (first) and 'better quality scaling' (second):

[image: photo scaling 400% straightforward]
[image]

(Credits for the two input test files belong to [*The Weizmann Institute of Science -- Faculty of Mathematics and Computer Science in Israel*](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/SingleImageSR.html) who have developed their own algorithm for image 'super resolution scaling'. The output shown here is however ImageMagick's and has nothing to do with the Weizmann Institute's algorithms...)

### 'The Command'

Finally, here is the command which gives you the superior quality. I ran it on ImageMagick v. *'6.7.6-9 2012-05-12 Q16'* to get the result you see in above images:

```
convert                       \
   input.png                  \
  -colorspace RGB             \
  +sigmoidal-contrast 11.6933 \
  -define filter:filter=Sinc  \
  -define filter:window=Jinc  \
  -define filter:lobes=3      \
  -resize 400%                \
  -sigmoidal-contrast 11.6933 \
  -colorspace sRGB            \
   better-quality-enlargement.png
```

**Disclaimer: This ImageMagick command is by no means my own achievement. It was the result of research by [*Nicolas Robidoux*](http://www.ohloh.net/accounts/NicolasRobidoux) who came up with it.**

More details about Nicolas' recent ImageMagick experiments, his explanations and considerations, and a few alternative commands of him you can find here:

- [**Sigmoidized Ginseng (pronounced "Jinc-Sinc") resampling**](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=21703)
- [**Improved Lanczos Enlargement with Sigmoidization**](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=21660)
- [**Improved EWA LanczosSharp with Sigmoidization**](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=21695)

Comment: That's very nice. I mean, I thought it was impossible to achieve such results without some manual effort.  Thank you for this!